# Are there ways to do factory re-set on LG phone by connecting to laptop via USB?

Tags: factory-reset, screen, lg

Are there ways to do factory re-set on LG phone by connecting to laptop via USB?
================================================== ==

I did review similar questions on internet, but the links provided for adb is broken.

I have LG tribute HD 4G LTE smartphone with Android (6.0 Marshmallow). It worked good but White Vertical Lines showing up now.

I took the battery out an put it back after a while. It did not fix the issue.

This phone did not expose to water.

The bad screens display vertical lines with a white background. Has anyone else had this problem?

If I press power on button, the screen with white lines comes and screen goes black. I am not able to get to dial pad to do unlock/re-set.

Is there any way to do factory re-set, by connecting the smart phone to computer via USB?

Any idea to fix this ?

I did download android studio, but I did not find an option to do reset my phone via USB.

I did find some steps using adb command line, but I am not sure what are the adb tools required to do.

```
I did find android studio, installed platform-tools at

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

adb root
throws:
adb: unable to connect for root: no devices/emulators found
```

Thanks for helping.

I am not able to enable USB Debugging from my phone, because vertical white lines is not allowing me to use phone screen

```
Here are the adb commands/results, I tried.

>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully


>adb devices
List of devices attached

>adb shell
error: no devices/emulators found
```

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Fe-flashing the firmware using a PC is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Is there a thread/tutorial to show flashing the firmware using a PC steps? What are the tools /software required ?  I am not able to enable USB Debugging from my phone, because vertical white lines is not allowing me to use phone screen 

Here are the adb commands/results, I tried.

>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully


>adb devices
List of devices attached

>adb shell
error: no devices/emulators found Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/lg-tribute-hd-ls676-stock-firmware-t3595963

Comment: Thanks. I did review the links. Some folks claims their device was dead after using the software, that caused downgrade. How do I make sure, my device will be safe after this ?

Comment: Believe. Some users wouldn't post/recommend it if their device wasn't  fixed by that file.

Comment: the zip file extracted to LS676ZV3_00.oct , how do I run this file ?

Comment: http://lgtribute.com/lg-tribute-hd-ls676-stock-rom-firmware-unbrick-guide/

Comment: I did download 4 items listed there. I connected my phone via USB to PC. It shows white vertical lines, LGUP complains "There is no handset connected, please connect a handset. The device is showing in windows explorer.